# Single reflecting mirror surface on WebGL

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl

I'm working on a very complex animation using WebGL. As you can see on the picture. It is a hallway with audio analysers on the walls and light strips on the sides. However, the floor looks empty and I want to make it look like it is made out of glass. To do that, I was thinking about making it reflect the walls on its surface.

[image: 3D audio animation project]

I'm a little bit new to WebGL. I do know how to do basic stuff like I already have, but I don't know how to do reflections. Google didn't help me out with this question.

As an update: I tried  but it is currently not working. It says no buffer is bound to enable attribute. Anything like typos that I could have made?

```
    function drawMirrors(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) {
        let shader = ResourceManager["shaders"]["blit_frame"];
        let buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        let posAtt = gl.getAttribLocation(shader, "vertPosition");
        let prjUni = gl.getUniformLocation(shader, "projMat");
        let vewUni = gl.getUniformLocation(shader, "viewMat");
        let scnUni = gl.getUniformLocation(shader, "scneMat");
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        x1, y1, z1, x1, y1, z2, x2, y1, z2, x1, y1, z1, x2, y1, z2, x2, y1, z1,
        x1, y2, z1, x1, y2, z2, x2, y2, z2, x1, y2, z1, x2, y2, z2, x2, y2, z1
        ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(posAtt, 3, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 3 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(posAtt);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, mirrorTex); // mirrorTex is a texture bound to a framebuffer that contains the two mirror perspecives.
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.useProgram(shader);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prjUni, gl.FALSE, projMat);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(vewUni, gl.FALSE, viewMat);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(scnUni, gl.FALSE, scneMat);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 12);
        gl.deleteBuffer(buffer);
    }

precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 vertPosition;

uniform mat4 projMat;
uniform mat4 viewMat;
uniform mat4 scneMat;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projMat * viewMat * scneMat * vec4(vertPosition, 1.0);
}

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D Sampler0;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(Sampler0, gl_FragCoord.xy/2.0+1.0);
    if (color.a == 0.0) discard;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the floor is say `Y=0` and your objects are in the positive side then you have to negate all `Y` coordinates when rendering the "mirror side".

If the geometry remains simple, no lightning, but only plain textured triangles, then is very straight forward:

1. Flip the model view matrix (multiply by the scaled (1,-1,1) matrix)
2. Render the scene, except the floor
3. Restore the model view matrix
4. Render the scene, including the floor

Else...

1. If you have lightning you have to move the lights to the negative side.
2. You might have to flip the cull face as well, if your geometry needs that.
3. You can use stencil testing to limit the drawing only on certain area (say the floor only).
4. You render everything that is to be reflected on the opposite (negative) side of the floor (negating all Y coordinates, per vertex).
5. Then you clear the depth buffer, and stop the stencil test if any.
6. After all of that you might render semi-transparent surface (quad), where the floor is, to look like there is an actual glass between the reflection and the other geometry
7. Then you restore the lights positions, and other changes that were made.
8. Draw your geometry as usual.

There are examples for this all over. It could be easy to understand if you look for some OpenGL mirror examples.

If you are not using any framework, you will need to do some math, especially related to the light, because of the WebGL machinery.

Comment: Please post everything related to the question in the question itself.

Comment: Already figured it out. I just had to disable the attributes I've applied to the previous shader.